# Json doesnt save properly using node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I am connected to websocket, each time i get message i save its content to a json file.If i get two or more messages in the same second it doesnt save it properly.How can i prevent that ?Each time i get message I am using :

```
  fs.readFile(bought_path,'utf-8',(err,data) =>{ ...
  //do something
```

to read json file , and

```
fs.writeFile(bought_path, JSON.stringify(kupljeni_itemi) , 'utf-8');
```

to save edited json file.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question exactly but one way that I'm thinking about trying to fix these problems if they do occur is by using something like the [jsonrepair](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonrepair) package when reading files.

Answer (score 1):

One way to guard is to make a simple locking mechanism:

```
let isLocked = false; // declare it in an upper scope.

if (!isLocked) { // check if it is not locked by other socket call.
  isLocked = true; // set the lock before writing the content
  fs.writeFile(file, json, (err) => {
    isLocked = false; // unlock when you get the response
  })
}
```

Comment: That's cool and all, but you need an `else` block that requeues the write if the resource is locked.

Answer (score -1):

you could use synchronous read/write functions - 
`readFileSync` and `writeFileSync`

Comment: That's a terrible idea: you're degrading performance for all requests to fix an intermittent problem.

Comment: totally depends on the nature of requests your server is handling. If most of the requests are file operations, then I do not see a difference in implementing a lock vs sync operations.

Comment: The **whole point** of node.js' existence (see Ryan Dahl's posts from when he released it) is that it's a non-blocking event loop-based server. If you're going to block on every file io, then why use node *at all*? I'm not saying that the sync versions have no use, they exist, but they are not for production code.

Comment: I agree with you on this. but again, trying to achieve something synchronously in a language designed for async programming, you'll have to trade off some performance. In the solution below with lock, about requeuing a write request, if you are constantly requeueing without a time interval, it's essentially using cpu time doing nothing. on the other hand, if you are requeueing with a time interval, what if the server is idle and not accepting no other requests at that point ? point being, no solution is a terrible idea( especially when it is offered as a part of native api)